# Python: How to add signal handler to asyncio HTTP server

Tags: http, asynchronous, webserver, signals, python-asyncio

My HTTP runs using aiohttp.web module:

```py
import asyncio     as aio
import aiohttp.web as web

server = web.Application()
server.add_routes([...])

web.run_app(server, port=8080)
```

The code inside `web.run_app` use the main event loop, it handles `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and exit when Ctrl+C is pressed, in simple apps. However, I need to terminate all threads, which aiohttp.web won't, and the programme doesn't exit.

How to override the default signal handler of aiohttp.web.Application?

Comment: If you control how threads are created, you can use `daemon=True` so they don't stall the main thread exiting.

Comment: Another straightforward approach is to use `try: web.run_app(server, port=8000) finally: <tell threads to exit>`. Handling signals manually is rarely a good idea, unless you really understand the details.

Comment: tks, adding daemon=True works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user4815162342 in the comments, 2 solutions for the problem:

Solution 1: Add `daemon=True`:

```
my_thread = Thread(target=..., daemon=True)
```

Solution 2: Wrap `web.run_app` in a `try` block:

```
try:
    web.run_app(server,...)
finally:
    terminate_threads()
```